# Chrome doesn't render xhtml?

Tags: google-chrome

Open local xhtml files in chrome, however, chrome treats it as XML files, and won't render it as HTML.

I don't want to change all my *.xhtml file extension to .html, so is there any workaround?

**EXAMPLE**

a.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>Hello</b>, 
        <i>World</i>!
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you pastebin an example xhtml file?  I did a test on my computer and google chrome opened up my xhtml file without issue.  Perhaps you have the wrong DOCTYPE declared?

Comment: The DOCTYPE is actually pretty irrelevant for browsers nowadays, one could just as well use `<!DOCTYPE html>` in an XML file and thus use XHTML5. It's the namespace that's important. The DOCTYPE can still be interesting for validation, especially for offline validation with XHTML 1.1 Second Edition when mixing modular XHTML it with other namespaces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you declared XHTML-1.0 strict your html tag needs an xml namespace:

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

A few other validation issues: you need a character set declaration and your text needs a `<p>` around it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>
        <b>Hello</b>, 
        <i>World</i>!
      </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While the solution is correct, the reason is slightly different. Browsers usually do not load external entities. The DTD would default the xmlns attribute to the XHTML namespace, but the external entity of the DTD is not loaded. The xmlns is required for XHTML in general, not because of the XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype. Unless you use that namespace, the browser will simply have no idea that your XML elements are actually HTML.

Comment: And the encoding declaration isn't needed. XML has a [detection mechanism](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-guessing) and explicitly says that on the [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-XMLDecl), the encoding is optional.

Comment: Also note the URL of the `xmlns`: it’s `http`! I continue to see xhtml documents that declare the namespace URL as `https` and that doesn’t work for Chrome.